# Stuck in grub_rescue and no access bios

Tags: grub2, bios, grubrescue, sata, ahci

I'm stuck in Grub_rescue on my laptop. I can only boot from Ubuntu Live USB, but in the installation, he does not recognise my SSD. Normally you should change the SATA-mode in the bios, but there is a problem with getting into the bios of my Acer-laptop. Is there a way where I can my SSD on my live Ubuntu while my SATA-mode is in AHCI?
The goal is to format my SSD...

Thanks in advance

S.

Comment: You should express yourself clearly this question is a bit complex in verbal form... As for the "goal is to format my SSD" part , you can format it from Live USB via GParted.
I don't think it's a SSD formatting problem , you need to be able to get into your BIOS.

Comment: I want to format my SSD and install Ubuntu on it. Gparted does not recognise my SSD because the sata-mode is on AHCI. But I can not change the Sata mode.
So I'm looking for a way that my Live Ubuntu USB recognize my SSD in AHCI mode.

Comment: And the SATA-mode should be AHCI, so that is not the problem.

Comment: Then how is it that Ubuntu can't see my disk/SSD?